# Loading Different CSS Styles for Specific Browsers [Not IE]

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, safari

I'm currently working on a website that keeps everything on one page instead of loading and linking to multiple HTML pages. That being said I'm having some trouble with formatting for different browsers.

Here is my website:
[Peranthai.com](http://peranthai.com)

The content loads fine in the Google Chrome browser(Browser it was built for), and the newest IE browser. I'm having some issues however (that could likely be solved with other style sheets for different browsers). I don't know how to do this though. I know that Internet Explorer has conditionals for this but the website works fine in Explorer so those are irrelevant to me. In particular these are the problems I'm having:

-Firefox turns some of the margins a little screwy

-Safari doesn't load background gradients

-Opera doesn't load one of my Adsense ads.

These are issues that, like I said, I could fix with custom style-sheets for certain browsers but I can't seem to figure out how to implement this.

[The reason you don't see content on the pages is because it isn't there yet! Just the base website is done]

Comment: Your approach to the problem isn't very good. No modern browsers, not even IE, have conditionals. There are some hacks, but they are fragile, and could easily break in the future. Start with one issue, and try to create CSS rules that work cross-browser for that issue. Often-times, issues like this are simply caused by different default styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a doctype. So the website is displayed in quirks mode.
And since different browsers have different quirks, naturally the website will look different among browsers.

Solution: add a DOCTYPE declaration.

Oh, and get rid of the `<center>`, it makes your page look amateuristic. Not to mention errors like `<h3>..</h2>`.

Comment: top that off with running it through w3c html/css validators. then if you have issues, note the browser and its version. most can be targeted with ua specific style sheets, and in rare cases you can feature detect/sniff with javascript to serve up the special styles. but i would listen to what Mr Lister says first and foremost.